# Setting up Position fixed

Tags: css

I am trying to set a position fixed to an image I have in the top of the page of a mobile view

[image]

```
  .fixed {
    position: fixed;
  }
```

this is with Ionic

```
<div class="item item-image polygon">
  <img src="http://urbanetradio.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/banner.jpg"
       class="fixed">
</div>
```

here is what I need, but fixed

[image]

**UPDATE**

here is a JSBin where I've attached the image to the background, but I can't see the image http://jsbin.com/puxavoveci/2/edit?html,css,output

Comment: What do you mean by _... but fixed?_ Is it not fixed? Do you need to add some coordinates: `top: 0` etc?

Answer (score 0):

CSS:

```
.fixed{
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

Try this. Hope this helps.

But I guess putting the image as only `img` won't get your desired output. I think you need to put that image in a `div` and make it a background image and give a CSS of `background-attachment: fixed;`

Or, can you please provide some fiddle for your html structure. Just want to see it and enhance my answer to a more relevant one

Edited:

CSS:

```
.fixed {
    background-image: url('http://urbanetradio.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/banner.jpg');
    background-attachment: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    min-height: 400px;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
 }
```

Am I right with the class I've targeted ? :) Hope this will work.

Comment: You may be right about the background/div thing. I can fix the image, but could only stretch it using `width: 100vh`.

Comment: You mean the background image can be stretch by giving the `div` a CSS of `width: 100%;` ? I think you can stretch the background image by giving the div a CSS of `background-size: cover;`

Comment: is not taking the image, here is the Plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/9tYTPM7DaRfn2QY41UOz?p=preview

Comment: No, I meant I can stretch the `img` using `100vw`.

Comment: it is weird, the image gets bigger but not fixed. Try editing this JSBin please. Why it would be that tricky ? http://jsbin.com/puxavoveci/2/edit?html,css,output

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Test for errors.

z-index:-1 will make it 1 layer below the rest of the page so that other content will scroll on top of it.

```
.absolute {
        position: absolute;
        top:0px;
        left:0px;
        width:100%;
        z-index:-1;
          }
    <div class="item item-image polygon">
      <img src="http://urbanetradio.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/banner.jpg"
           class="absolute">
    </div>
```

Comment: try it with z-index. i just added it. didn't realize that you wanted the page content to scroll on top of it.

Comment: ya im on your fiddle, i'm surprised z-index isn't handling this. perhaps there is something else in your src codes that is overriding it. nice app btw. it will look sharp once you get the image as the background.